# laravel eloquent model record not fetched

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am facing a strange issue. When I do `NumberConfiguration::all()` I receive the following result:

```
[{"id":1,"created_at":"2022-09-13 09:48:51+0200","updated_at":"2022-09-13 09:49:12+0200","block_start":"41582550003","block_end":"41582550003","number_block_id":1,"special_numbers":null}]
```

but in the database I have actually 2 record:
[image]

I didnt find anything what can cause this problem, that not all record are represented by the eloquent model biding. I am using postgresql database.

There is an observer in the parent class, but even if I comment it out the same problem occurs.

```
class NumberConfiguration extends BaseConcreteProductConfiguration
{

protected $table = 'shop.numbers_configurations';

// Needs to be present in every ConcreteConfiguration file who has a Observer with action on cart to order
protected $fillable = [ 'updated_at' ];


protected $casts = [ 'special_numbers' => 'array' ];

public static function getValidations(string $prefix = ''): array
{
    return [
        $prefix . 'block_start'     => [ 'nullable' ],
        $prefix . 'block_end'       => [ 'nullable' ],
        $prefix . 'number_block_id' => [ 'nullable', 'numeric' ],
        $prefix . 'special_numbers' => [ 'nullable' ],
    ];
}

public static function getManager(): ConfigurationManagerInterface
{
    return new NumberConfigurationManager();
}

public function getDescription(): ?string
{
    $numberBlock = NumberBlock::find($this->number_block_id);

    if (!is_null($numberBlock)) {
        $numbers = $numberBlock->numbers()->pluck('did');

        if (!empty($numbers)) {
            return NumberManager::groupNumberToDisplayWithLocalPrefix(NumberManager::groupNumbersByRange($numbers))
                ->reduce(fn($a, $b) => $a . $b . ' ');
        } else {
            \Log::warning('configuration description not available, no numbers for block: '
                          . $this->number_block_id);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

Any help is higly appriciated.

Comment: are you using soft deletes?

Comment: I dont use softdeletes

Comment: Okay, can you check if any global scope is being used? You could do NumberConfiguration::withoutGlobalScopes()->get();

Comment: Thanks. It looks like a global scope is in use, I can retrieve the item withoutGlobalscope! Do you know where does global scopes are defined to check what is the problem?

Comment: Check this out: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#writing-global-scopes
They are an independent class and they are called on the model usually on the boot method. May I post this as an answer and you mark it correct for other users?

Comment: Cheers, if you need help in the future hit me in my email: kevinsada05@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out for global scopes.

```
NumberConfiguration::withoutGlobalScopes()->get();
```

This is how you disable global scopes and retrieve everything.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#writing-global-scopes